# How to allow remote hold music through on a FreeSWITCH rtp proxy?

Tags: freeswitch

With our freeswich RTP proxy our users hear a silent sound when the remote party puts us on hold. We want to hear the remote system's hold music instead. We want to accept the remote party's hold music

We have a system that proxies calls through FreeSwitch to allow us to deal with Nat Traversal as well as do some transcoding in certain specific cases. We found that when our party put the remote party on hold it would play FreeSwitch's Hold music instead of our master PBX's hold music. When the remote party put our party on hold our party would also hear freeswitch's hold music. 
To fix the issue when our party putting the remote party on hold and freeswitch's hold music we changed the hold music in the vars.xml file to  this then made it so that our PBX would put the hold music to the remote party.

````xml
<X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="hold_music=indicate_hold"/>
```xml

When the remote party puts our caller on hold we expect to hear the hold music from the remote party's PBX. We currently hear silence.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways.

The first is to set `disable-hold` to `true` in the sip_profile the hold signaling is coming in on:

```xml
<param name="disable-hold" value="true"/>
```

See `disable-hold` information [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Sofia+Configuration+Files).

And the second is to set `rtp_disable_hold=true` in the dialplan where that the call is routing through.

```xml
<action application="set" data="rtp_disable_hold=true"/>
```

See `rtp_disable_hold=true` information [here](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/rtp_disable_hold).

The second option gives you flexibility to remove the option later on, or to not disable hold music in other scenarios where you may want to use Freeswitch hold music.